# How can I replace an OS partition with another?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, operating-systems

I have Windows XP, Ubuntu 9.04, and Ubuntu 9.10 beta on my hard drive. When 9.10 final comes out, I want to overwrite the partitions for 9.04 and 9.10 with a fresh install, but leave the Windows partition untouched. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Since you are doing this, you should separate your Ubuntu in two partitions, one for /home and one for / so next time you can keep your own files (just without problems.

Comment: i always recommend a decent bootmanager (e.g. BootIt™ NG, BootStar) that will properly hide partitions from other operating systems to avoid such confusions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the easiest way would be to simply put in the installer disk and delete the partitions with Ubuntu on, and then create a new one that takes up the free space - assuming they are next to each other (and that the Ubuntu installer will still let you do this).

If the partitions are not next to each other when you delete, you may need to get [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/), or your favourite partition editor and move them around.